# Can I recover the `~/` short-cut?

Tags: nautilus

I upgraded to 10.10 on Sunday, from 10.04, and while the upgrade went smoothly (and I really like Maverick so far) I've somehow lost the `~/` short-cut. Previously, if I was in directory `/var/www/siteName/` and I typed `~/` into the location/address bar I'd be taken to `/home/username/`, whereas now it seems to be treated as a relative path, and I'm taken to the (non-existant) `/var/www/siteName/~/` directory.

Can I restore the previous functionality? I seem to recall that I `Okay`-ed a dialogue during the installation, but I can't, for the life of me, remember what it said. Or if it gave any clues as to how to later change that opinion.

---

**Edited** to note that, as of Ubuntu 11.04, the `~/` shortcut has been restored.

Comment: I've added the nautilus tag because your comment to fluteflute's answer made it clear you're talking about nautilus.

Comment: @sepp2k, thanks, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug [has now been fixed](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/630512) in 10.10

Comment: That certainly works in the terminal/shell, but I was rather hoping for a GUI/nautilus option, if such exists?

Comment: Sorry I miss understood you quite badly there! I've reported a bug for you: http://edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/659411

Comment: wow, thank you! =) I hadn't considered it bug-worthy, to be honest, I was pretty certain it was, effectively, stupidity-based... (to my shame) =/

Comment: It's a bug and it's since been referred upstream: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632009